# How to configure and enable Spring Data REST using XML?

Tags: xml, maven, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I guess I'm old school, but I prefer XML configuration over JavaConfig.

How do I correctly configure Spring Data REST using Maven and only XML Spring configuration files?

I have a simple app up and running with Postgres, Hibernate, a Spring Data JPA repository, and a Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using spring-data-rest-webmvc version 1.1.0.M1...

in `applicationContext.xml`, you need:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.packagename.repository"/>
```

and in `web.xml`, you need:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SDR 1.1.0.M1 seems to require:

```
spring-data-jpa 1.3.5.RELEASE
spring-webmvc 3.2.7.RELEASE
spring-hateoas 0.8.0.RELEASE
```